# Change ListBox background color

Tags: c#, colors, background, listbox, windows-8

I have a `ListBox` written in [xaml](/questions/tagged/xaml):

```xml
<ListBox Margin="0" x:Name="ListBox_Main" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="24" SelectionChanged="ListBox_Main_SelectionChanged" Foreground="Black">
    <ListBoxItem Content="Item 1" Background="#19000000" />
    <ListBoxItem Content="Item 2" Background="#19000000" />
    <ListBoxItem Content="Item 3" Background="#19000000" />
    <ListBoxItem Content="Item 4" Background="#19000000"/>
    <ListBoxItem Content="Item 5" Background="#19000000"/>
 </ListBox>
```

We can see the background color is `#19000000`, can we change the color in C#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the background color using a brush:

```
var item = ListBox_Main.Items[0] as ListBoxItem ;
item.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 0));
```